# Передача объекта в функцию по значению

Tags: javascript

Можно ли передать объект в функцию по значению, а не по ссылке? Например, если передаем массив в рекурсивную функцию, и на каждом вызове из этого массива удаляется один элемент:

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3];
...
function fun(a) {
  a.splice(0, 1);
  fun(a);
}
```

Изначальный массив `arr` должен остаться без изменений. Есть возможность такое сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Array.prototype.slice()
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice

```
fun(arr.slice());
```

Comment: эм... это ж не совсем то :-) просто создается новый массив :) а передача как была по ссылке, так и осталась

Comment: @Grundy - это один из случаев, когда автор просит не то, что ему нужно. Я руководствовался последней фразой вопроса.